# Modify field inside of Jsonb in Postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I was going through the Postgres Jsonb documentation but was unable to find a solution for a small issue I'm having.

I've got a table : MY_TABLE

that has the following columns:

User, Name, Data and Purchased

One thing to note is that "Data" is a jsonb and has multiple fields. One of the fields inside of "Data" is "Attribute" but it is currently a string. How can I go about changing this to a list of strings?

I have tried using json_build_array but have not had any luck

So for example, I'd want my jsonb to look like :

```
   {
       "Id": 1,
       "Attributes": ["Test"]

   }
```

instead of

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Attributes": "Test"

}
```

I only care about the "Attributes" field inside of the Json, not any other fields.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: @GMB just updated the question, thanks for responding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `jsonb_set()` and `jsonb_build_array()`, like so:

```
jsonb_set(js, '{Attributes}', jsonb_build_array(js->> 'Attributes'))
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=829458e7f9a9a244a7c1f51581a93f8e)**:

```
with t as (select '{ "Dd":1, "Attributes":"Test"}'::jsonb js)
select 
    js, 
    jsonb_set(js, '{Attributes}', jsonb_build_array(js->> 'Attributes')) new_js
from t
```

```
js                              | new_js                           
:------------------------------ | :--------------------------------
{"Dd": 1, "Attributes": "Test"} | {"Dd": 1, "Attributes": ["Test"]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much - do you know how I could use my table in the query you provided? I've replaced '{ "Id:1, "Attributes : "Test"}' with MY_TABLE.data but getting syntax issues.

Comment: @blazerix: `select jsonb_set(data, ...) from mytable`

Comment: I have the following:

    

`with t as (select jsonb_set(data) from public.mytable as js)
    select 
        js, 
        jsonb_set(js, '{Attributes}', jsonb_build_array(js->> 'Attributes')) new_js
    from t`

but it says function jsonb_set does not exist

Comment: @blazerix: no. Just: `select data, jsonb_set(data, '{Attributes}', jsonb_build_array(data ->> 'Attributes')) new_data from mytable`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for. I will read more into jsonb_set and jsonb_build_array so I have a more clear understanding.